# Multi-store sales report error

Tags: multistore, reports

I've been going crazy with this for a few days now.  I'm having problems with my multi-store sales report.  I have 3 stores on one magento.  They are called English, French and Dealer. When I run a report (yes I use lifetime) for All Websites I only get the sales from Dealer.  It doesn't show the other stores.  When I ask for reports for Dealers, it works.  When I ask for reports for English or French, I get $0 but I have had sales in those areas.

This is a new site so it never worked and is on 1.9.2.0.  I have a feeling it's a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the currency rate. Even if it's 1/1. It seems that without it, lifetime sales will stay at 0 for other stores.